# How to make feathers on a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, effects

This is my first question here. So hello. Anyway, my question is: how could I make it look like a mesh is covered in feathers?

For example I am making a few scientifically acurate dinosaur models i.e velociraptor and many were covered in feathers.

I need to be able to see it both on render (cycles) and when I export my mesh into the unity game engine.

Textures or a modifier of some sort? any help would be fantastic!

Comment: You're in luck - Pierrick Picaut recently posted a timelapse modeling video and .blend of a fantastic bird model on Blender Artists. His is more on the cartoon side stylistically but there's no reason you couldn't use the technique for realism too. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?377202-The-Bird-blend-file-included As for exporting a mesh with particles into Unity, I don't know. Maybe someone else can comment on that.

Comment: If you have feathers as a particle system you can go to the modifier stack and hit convert. That way it made the particles into seperate objects which can be transported ( it will probably be resource heavy unless the feather models aren't that high poly )